# Cheapest way from Belgium(Europe) to Egypt? (flight or ferry)

Tags: ferries, egypt

I need to go to Egypt from, I will going back from another country, so a single ticket would be enough.
I don't mind flying from another European country since Brussels is well connected by budget airlines, preferably from Cyprus, my question is, are there now any ferry still running to Egypt and how they expensive?